# ReferenceError: google_tag_manager is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, google-tag-manager

I am using google_tag_manager on My Dating Website for analytics ...I have seen Basic tutorial on how to implement google_tag_manager ...and generated the code from the controller and put up in my mark up ...still it is showing Error ..

It stated following Error :

```
Reference Error: google_tag_manager is not defined


haw_snowplow("newTracker", "", "d1663cp6879lbv.cloudfront.net", { appId: "dating", platform: "web", cookieDomain: "howaboutwe.com", encodeBase64: !0, contextVendor: "com.howaboutwe" }); haw_snowplow("setUserId", google_tag_manager["GTM-NPFN82"].macro(6)); haw_snowplow("trackPageView", null);
```

This is my markup

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
</head>
<body class="unified-dedicated_dating_facebook">
    <noscript>
        <iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-NPFN82" height="0" width="0"
            style="display: none; visibility: hidden"></iframe>
    </noscript>
    <script>
        (function (w, d, s, l, i) {
            w[l] = w[l] || []; w[l].push({ 'gtm.start':
                    new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js'
            });
            var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                j = d.createElement(s),
                dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';

            j.async = true;
            j.src = '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
            f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
        })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-NPFN82');
    </script>
    <script id="" type="text/javascript">
        (function(a, e, f, g, b, c, d) {
             a[b] || (a.GlobalSnowplowNamespace = a.GlobalSnowplowNamespace || [], a.GlobalSnowplowNamespace.push(b), a[b] = function () { (a[b].q = a[b].q || []).push(arguments) }, a[b].q = a[b].q || [], c = e.createElement(f), d = e.getElementsByTagName(f)[0], c.async = 1, c.src = g, d.parentNode.insertBefore(c, d))
        })(window, document, "script", "//d1fc8wv8zag5ca.cloudfront.net/2/sp.js", "haw_snowplow");
        haw_snowplow("newTracker", "", "d1663cp6879lbv.cloudfront.net", { appId: "dating", platform: "web", cookieDomain: "howaboutwe.com", encodeBase64: !0, contextVendor: "com.howaboutwe" }); haw_snowplow("setUserId", google_tag_manager["GTM-NPFN82"].macro(6)); haw_snowplow("trackPageView", null);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I remove the last script section

```
<script id="" type="text/javascript">
    (function(a, e, f, g, b, c, d) {
         a[b] || (a.GlobalSnowplowNamespace = a.GlobalSnowplowNamespace || [], a.GlobalSnowplowNamespace.push(b), a[b] = function () { (a[b].q = a[b].q || []).push(arguments) }, a[b].q = a[b].q || [], c = e.createElement(f), d = e.getElementsByTagName(f)[0], c.async = 1, c.src = g, d.parentNode.insertBefore(c, d))
    })(window, document, "script", "//d1fc8wv8zag5ca.cloudfront.net/2/sp.js", "haw_snowplow");
    haw_snowplow("newTracker", "", "d1663cp6879lbv.cloudfront.net", { appId: "dating", platform: "web", cookieDomain: "howaboutwe.com", encodeBase64: !0, contextVendor: "com.howaboutwe" }); haw_snowplow("setUserId", google_tag_manager["GTM-NPFN82"].macro(6)); haw_snowplow("trackPageView", null);
</script>
```

the Error goes Out ..
I am not able to find any good reference what is causing the issue ..

any suggestion will be helpful

Comment: You should execute that last bit only after google tag manager has loaded

Comment: i didnt understand ..I believe I have put up the code in proper order..and this is the only code for the google_Tag_Manager ...do i need to change the script order ?

Answer (score 1):

If the snippet after the gtm loading is also tracking code, you should insert it on a loaded event such as `gtm.load` inside gtm as a javascript snippet.